# With a command, how can I unbind the Super key in Windows 11

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11

When I press the super key in Windows 11, the Start Menu opens.

I don't want that to happen.

I want to unbind the Super key.

I also don't care if all the other S+letter keyboard shortcuts stops working.

I've found a few different ways to set this in the registry, but it seems it's a different key now with Windows 11.

What works on Windows 11?;)

I've tried:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer' -Name 'NoWinkeys' -Value 1 -Type DWORD
```

I have tested on both when in a domain and without, and after a restart, the value is still there, so it's not removed

```
PS C:\Users\esben.ID> $path = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer"
PS C:\Users\esben.ID> $name = "NoWinkeys"
PS C:\Users\esben.ID> Get-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name $name

NoWinkeys    : 1
PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies
               \Explorer
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies
PSChildName  : Explorer
PSDrive      : HKCU
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Just do not use the key. I have had Windows 11 Pro running for 2 years now. No keystroke issues.

Comment: Put a piece of foam rubber underneath it so you don't tap it accidentally; it will require slightly more pressure than other keys. That is what I do to Caps Lock.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable it via registry.  The registry value is

`\\HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoWinkeys`

It is a DWORD.  Set the value to 1.  If the value does not exist then you can just create it.  Once added / set reboot your PC.

Be aware that this can be overridden by group policy so if you are in a domain environment this tweak could be reset.

Comment: I did this, but I still am able to hit the Super key and the Start Menu pops up: Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer' -Name 'NoWinkeys' -Value 1 -Type DWORD . I am, however, in a domain, but how can I check if this tweak is reset?

Comment: I've tried this on three different Win-11 platforms now and none of them work. This last computer is not in a domain. Is this documented to be working somewhere? Does it work for you?;)